# Nested Let syntax in haskell confusion

Tags: haskell, let

```
main = let sumSquares = sum (map (^2) [1..100]) 
           squaredSum = sum [1..100] ^ 2 
           in sumSquares - squaredSum
```

New to Haskell, so I've been going back through Project Euler. I know my solution is sound, and it works when I don't bother with any lets.

For some reason, this gives me an error message. Can you help? Thank you!

Comment: what error message does it give you?

Comment: No instance for (Num (IO t0)) arising from a use of ‘-’
    In the expression: sumSquares - squaredSum
    In the expression:
      let
        sumSquares = sum (map (^ 2) [1 .. 100])
        squaredSum = sum [1 .. 100] ^ 2
      in sumSquares - squaredSum
    In an equation for ‘main’:
        main
          = let
              sumSquares = sum (map (^ 2) ...)
              squaredSum = sum ... ^ 2
            in sumSquares - squaredSum
Failed, modules loaded: none.

Comment: When adding information to your question, you should edit the question, not add comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have chosen to name this term `main`, without giving it the correct type.  A Haskell module with a `main` term is expected to define it with type `IO ()`, but you have given it an expression that looks something like `Num a => a`, by virtue of the `-`  This error happens because Haskell is looking for some sort of way to make `IO ..` an instance of `Num`, which it isn't.

Try naming it something else.

Comment: Minor nit: the type of `main` has to unify with `IO a`, and need not specifically be `IO ()`. Otherwise the answer is spot on.